# NullReferenceException error when trying to set localScale

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add picking up objects feature in my FPS game. Where when the object is picked up it will be placed in an empty game object which is a child of the main camera:

[image]

```
[SerializeField] private Transform PickupParent;
void Start()
{
PickupParent = transform.parent;
}
void Update()
{
 public void PickupObject()
        {
        
        physicsObject = lookObject.GetComponentInChildren<PhysicsObjects>();
        currentlyPickedUpObject = lookObject;
        pickupRB = currentlyPickedUpObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
       /* priorConstraints = pickupRB.constraints;    // <--- NEW
        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;    // <--- NEW*/
        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
        physicsObject.playerInteractions = this;
        pickupRB.isKinematic = true;
        pickupRB.transform.parent = PickupParent.transform;
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1 / PickupParent.transform.localScale.x, 1 / PickupParent.transform.localScale.y, 1/ PickupParent.transform.localScale.z);

        //  StartCoroutine(physicsObject.PickUp());
    }
}
```

It was not working as expected as the picked-up object changes scale every time it is picked up. I tried fixing the issue by adding this line:

```
transform.localScale = new Vector3(1 / PickupParent.transform.localScale.x, 1 / PickupParent.transform.localScale.y, 1/ PickupParent.transform.localScale.z);
```

but now it is not picking up object and every time I try to pick up an object it throws this error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ThePlayerInteractions.PickupObject () (at Assets/New Folder/Script/ThePlayerInteractions.cs:289)
ThePlayerInteractions.Update () (at Assets/New Folder/Script/ThePlayerInteractions.cs:147)
```

pointing to the same line. Why is this happening?

Comment: Why is pickupobject a sub method of update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like your issue:

```
[SerializeField] private Transform PickupParent;
void Start()
{
    PickupParent = transform.parent;
}
```

You're serializing `PickupParent` (meaning it can be set in the inspector) but then you're overwriting it in `Start()`.  If this script is placed on a root `GameObject` in the scene (i.e. a `GameObject` with no parent), then `transform.parent` will be `null` and so will `PickupParent`.  It seems like you should just remove the `Start()` function entirely and then set `PickupParent` in the inspector to whatever you'd like it to be.